# Possible to export the entire JSS (react-jss) stylesheet as a CSS string?

Tags: javascript, css, jss

Title really says it all here. My JSS sheet is connected to a rich text editor. We would like to save certain edited files as flat HTML/CSS files, and I’m not entirely sure how to access the full stylesheet.

How can I get the current JSS state as a string of CSS? Worth note: I’m using the now defunct react-jss package.

Answer (score 0):

when you call jss.createStyleSheet().toString() you get the generated CSS string, if you use react-jss, you can basically do the same thing that docs describe for SSR:

```
import {JssProvider, SheetsRegistry} from 'react-jss'

const sheets = new SheetsRegistry()

<JssProvider registry={sheets}>
  <MyApp />
</JssProvider>

sheets.toString()
```